Random number generator returning duplicate values
I have a random number generator I want to return 7 keys from a dictionary.
I am using random.uniform to generate a float value which I match to my set of values in my dictionary which are float values to produce the closest value and return the relevant key to that value.
I am iterating over a list to add any unique keys that are produced but ignoring any duplicate keys as I want to end up with a random set of numbers e.g. 5, 12, 6, 18, 28, 23, 15 not duplicate values such as, 5, 12, 5, 15, 23, 12, 5
My code to generate the set of numbers works:
count = 0
    while True:
        if count <= 6:
            number = ran.uniform(0.0, max_key)
            num_gen = min(sorted_countout, key=lambda x:abs(x-(number)))
            snumgen = list()
            if num_gen not in snumgen:
                snumgen.append(num_gen)
                count += 1
            else:
                count += 0
            print(snumgen)
        elif count > 6:
            break

However it isn't producing a unique set of numbers, I am still getting duplicate values in my produced set.
Also as a separate issue- how would I reset count outside of the loop? it completes the loop but then locks at 6- I have to close vscode to get it to generate a new set of numbers-
NOTE: There are some similar questions in this vein of questioning- but I am more specifically asking for a solution in this context as it should be producing unique numbers but it isn't currently. I am a junior dev and appreciate your help as it helps me learn!
##Here is an example of my dictionary:
sorted_countout = {1: 17.8343949044586, 2: 21.337579617834397, 3: 21.656050955414013, 4: 19.745222929936308, 5: 19.10828025477707, 6: 20.382165605095544, 7: 23.88535031847134, 8: 17.8343949044586, 9: 21.97452229299363, 10: 20.382165605095}

import random as ran

##this is the function
def choices():
    ##selecting the maximum value in the dict
    max_key = next(iter(sorted_countout))
    for key in sorted_countout:
        if sorted_countout[key] > sorted_countout[max_key]:
            max_key = key
    ##Randomly select a float value in range of 0- max freq of occurrence
    
    count = 0
    while True:
        if count <= 6:
            number = ran.uniform(0.0, max_key)
            num_gen = min(sorted_countout, key=lambda x:abs(x-(number)))
            snumgen = list()
            if num_gen not in snumgen:
                snumgen.append(num_gen)
                count += 1
            else:
                count += 0
            print(snumgen)
        elif count > 6:
            break


That's because you're instantiating your list inside the loop, so you reset it every cycle. Also, you need to set your counter back to 0 right after the loop:
def choices():
    max_key = next(iter(sorted_countout))
    for key in sorted_countout:
        if sorted_countout[key] > sorted_countout[max_key]:
            max_key = key

    count = 0
    snumgen = []  # Move the list initialization outside the loop
    while True:
        if count <= 6:
            number = ran.uniform(0.0, max_key)
            num_gen = min(sorted_countout, key=lambda x:abs(x-(number)))
            if num_gen not in snumgen:
                snumgen.append(num_gen)
                count += 1
            else:
                continue  # Skip duplicate numbers
        else:
            break

    print(snumgen)
    count = 0  # Reset count outside the loop


Awesome thankyou so much Yevhen! You immediately solved my problem- you are a Hero!
